# Translate Matlab to Mathematica, fixed-point iteration

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

This is my Matlab code:

```
clear;clc;format ('long','g')
i=1;
x(i)=0;
error(i) = 9999;

while error(i) >= 0.05
    x(i+1) = (0.2062129)*(20+(2*x(i)))^(2/5);
    error(i+1)=abs((((x(i+1)-x(i))/(x(i+1)))*100));
    i=i+1;
end

disp('           root                 error(%)');
disp([x',error'])
```

**How do I translate this into Mathematica so that it generates the list of roots and errors the way it does in matlab?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't have the output you got from Matlab it is difficult to know whether this is correct enough or not. Compare it to what you have and go from there.

```
expr={1,0,9999};
f[{i_,xi_,err_}]:=(xipp=0.2062129*(20+(2*xi))^(2/5);
  {i+1,xipp,Abs[(((xipp-xi)/(xipp))*100)]});
NestWhileList[f,expr,#[[3]]>=.05&]
```

which in a fraction of a second returns

```
{{1,0,9999},
 {2,0.683483,100.},
 {3,0.701799,2.60989},
 {4,0.70228,0.0684954},
 {5,0.702293,0.00179788}}
```

Comment: There is actually a built in function `FixedPoint` also

Comment: The solution worked perfectly sorry I meant to add the output from my Matlab code. On a side note what does xipp mean? I'm fairly new to mathematica.

Comment: Some languages have things like x++ which increments the value in x. That is sometimes called "plus plus". Your code had x(i) and x(i+1) which I translated into xi and xipp, for the incremented value of i. So it is just a variable name and not one of the thousands of Mathematica symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest instead of burying the convergence test in the function you do like this:

```
f[xi_] := 0.2062129*(20 + (2*xi))^(2/5)
NestWhileList[f, 0, Abs[(#2 - #1)/#2*100] >= .05 &, 2]
```

> {0, 0.683483, 0.701799, 0.70228, 0.702293}

You can also do:

```
FixedPointList[f, 0, SameTest -> (Abs[(#2 - #1)/#2*100] < .05 &)]
```

Note in both cases you can use  `FixedPoint` and `NestWhile` if you just want the final result ,  not the list of intermediate values.